# Finding the request came from which page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, user-controls

I have 2 pages, Page1 and Page2. Each Page has same user control "uc1". In the usercontrol, load event I want to find from which page the request has came, whether this user control is loaded from page1 or page2.

I know that with session I can do it, but I am not sure whether that is the best way.

Can anyone please advise on it ?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? User controls should be reusable, their behavior shouldn't change depending on the page they're hosted on.

Comment: add a variable to the control which provides a way for the page to set the optional behaviour. ie public bool IsPage1

Comment: @mason Depending on the page called, I want some small behavior change, so

Comment: This shouldn't be done by the user control detecting things. If pages want to modify the behavior of the user control, they should pass options to the user control, or wire up to events. Just like the built in controls.

Comment: **they should pass options to the user control, or wire up to events. Just like the built in controls.** I did not understood this

Answer (score 1):

What is your platform? In C# you can use Request.UrlReferrer, in other languages, I think, there is something similar